# Jquery hex color select and replace

Tags: jquery, css

Here is the problem I need to use jquery to find and replace certain background colors in tables.

```
<table>
<tr bgcolor="#9BB9FB"><td>contect</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#cccccc"><td>contect</td></tr>
</table>
```

I am currently using this jauery statement :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() {


 $('*').filter(function() {
 var match = 'rgb(155, 185, 251)';
 return ( $(this).css('background-color') == match );
 }).css('background-color', '#E6B8B7'); 

 });
```

But I need to search for the #color not the rgb. Also I need to look for several     different colors and change their colours respectively.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you need the filter, but if you're using jQuery you can select using the attribute selector as such :

```
$('tr[bgcolor="#9BB9FB"]').attr('bgcolor','#000000');
```

no other code needed, rinse and repeat :)

**Edit:** IE compatibility needs quotes around the attrib selector value

Comment: Perfect, thankyou I must of been over complicating it. 
 
Any Idea why this wont work in IE9 ??

Comment: can you verify that this fiddle does not work for you ?

http://jsfiddle.net/wB3Cd/

Comment: No the fiddle wont work in IE 7 8 or 9, Works in all the other browsers though. Its been a proper head banger just cant figure out why IE wont do the changed .. Thanks again

Comment: edited the code above, it only needs the color value to be wrapped in ""